C# MAUI Event GraphicsView StartInteraction not working
If i tap on GraphicsView should event and call method tap, but debugger does not respond on tap. Label do not change too.
XAML:
<Label 
    x:Name="lb"
    Text="You touch nothing"/>

<GraphicsView
    x:Name="tralala"
    StartInteraction="tap"/>

CS:
private void tap(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    lb.Text = "You touch my tralala"
}

I try add GestureRecognizers :
<GraphicsView
    x:Name="previewer"
    StartInteraction="tap">

    <GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers >

        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="tapp"/>
        
    </GraphicsView.GestureRecognizers>
    
</GraphicsView>

CS:
private void tapp(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    lb.Text = "You touch my tralala"
}

but this not helping

What platform did you test on? I can't reproduce your problem on android and windows. Did you try to set the value of heightrequest and widthrequest?

platform - Android Pixel 3a API 30 - Android 11

I tried right now and it works! Thank you bloody match!

Liyun Zhang, do your know what is the way to get the distance between two points?
In WPF i used:
var dis = Point.SubtractfirstPosition, secondPosition).Length.
Does MAUI have an equivalent of this?


If i tap on GraphicsView should event and call method tap, but debugger does not respond on tap

The GraphicsView's default HeightRequest and WidthRequest is -1 on android, so you need to set the value of them to make the GraphicsView can render on the screen.
You can get the distance by : var dis = firstpoint.Distance(secondpoint). Just check the source code: public double Distance.
And for more information about the api, you can check the official document about Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Point.

The GraphicsView as Liyung said, should have heightRequest//WidthRequest to ensure that the view is not obstructed by other controls (defauylt values are -1), so if you set those values, the tap will be recognized in graphicsView Zone:
<GraphicsView
    x:Name="tralala"
    HeightRequest="setvalue"
    WidthRequest="setvalue"
    StartInteraction="tap"/>

And to get the distance between 2 points you could use the following using the Point structure of library Microsoft.Maui.Graphics:
public double GetDistance(Point firstPosition, Point secondPosition)
{
    double axisX = secondPosition.X - firstPosition.X;
    double axisY = secondPosition.Y - firstPosition.Y;
    return Math.Sqrt(axisX * axisX + axisY * axisY);
}

